# New number sequence

Tags: php

I need to generate an incremental sequence number to add a new record.
In my case I use a query to check how many records table have and add +1 to have next number.

When user create a new entry this number is displayed on screen.

[add.php]

ENTRY: 20

Name:

Surname:

CODE

```
    $next= mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mod_dps'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($next);
    $next_id= $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Now, when 2 users open same window, number is identical, because page call same query and add 1 on total rows. Number change only when 1st user save a record.

Anyone have a tip to solve this problem, in fact I need 2 or more person can add records but each with differnet and incremental number.

Thanks all

Comment: look up autoincrement and let mysql handle it.  no need for php to play a part.

Comment: Cool, but auto increment work only if 1st user SAVE record. How to handle 2 or more users to have incremental sequence without save record?

Comment: Create the entry (ill advised) and return the value to the browser. Use a stored procedure to clear out empty records..... (I really hate even suggesting this)

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't provide the number. Such a number is just an internal thing. You don't need it until you're actually going to save something. So: when adding a new record, just present a form without the number. When saving, save the new record and get the number assigned to it. When editing, remember the number (in the session or in the form, or both) and save the modified data by the number.